# Emacs Dired: Retain lines instead of dired-do-kill-lines?

Tags: emacs, dired

You can easily kill marked lines in **Emacs Dired** by typing in *k* or running the command *dired-do-kill-lines*. Is it also possible to retain the marked files and kill the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just toggle your selection first (t).